# Can blender be used to re-target animations to other rigs?

Tags: animation

I do this in Maya where you can re-target say a walk cycle from one humanoid onto another. Can one do this in blender?

Answer (score 7):

An action can be assigned to another object in the [action editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/DopeSheet/Action). This only works for armatures if the bones have matching names.

For more difficult re-targeting just enable the Motion Capture Tools addon that is included with blender. [The addon's wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/Motion_Capture_Tools) includes links to the manual and video tutorials for using it.

> At the heart of the system, is the retargeting tool, which allows artists to transfer animations from the imported mocap armature to their own rig.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [blender-retarget](https://github.com/igelbox/blender-retarget) addon could help you. To use it, just do the following steps:

- Align the target skeleton bones along with the source ones.
- And toggle the "Link location" / "Link rotation" buttons.

And that's it, now target bones follow the source ones.
Also, target bones transform can be adjusted at any time.

For more details, refer the README on the GitHub project.