# Copy animation onto skeleton with different bone orientations

Tags: animation, armature, bones

First off I want to say that my question is kind of hard for me to put into words,so I apologize if this is hard to understand. I'm trying to port animations from one game to another for a mod I'm making.

The animations I want to port has its skeleton bones rotated differently from the other game's skeleton. How can I port the animations onto the other game's skeleton while retaining its original bone rotation?

I just know it's possible to do this somehow,since someone did it before: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=832086722

I've asked the creator of this mod the same question but they never replied,which is why I came here to try and find out the process. If you need pictures,more details,or even a blend file,I can provide them.

Comment: What you are looking for is "retargeting", which is quite complex and needs an addon: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26216/can-blender-be-used-to-re-target-animations-to-other-rigs

Comment: How do I use retargeting to port these animations?

Comment: It's too broad for this site, you must read all the documentation indicated in the link.

Comment: I've watched a few videos by Benjy Cook on retargeting,but I still can't figure out how to get it to work.

https://imgur.com/a/xli7F this is a picture of the bone rotations.

Comment: Can I send you a blend file to try and help me?