# Transfer animation between two armatures that have the same structure and naming conventions but differing rest poses?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, keyframes

I have a skinned armature in a T-pose as its rest pose that is not animated and a second separate armature that has an animation I would like to transfer to the first skinned mesh. The only problem is that the armature I want to transfer the animation from is in a diffrerent rest pose than the target armature, and since the animation is done relative to the bones' local positions and not global space, the animation just copied and pasted to the first armature looks very wrong. EDIT: I also cannot change the skinned armature's rest pose as it needs to be that way for a specific program I'm importing it into.

Is there a way to convert the animation such that the bone offsets can be changed to the skinned armature? Something I thought of would be that empties would be made in global space that would align in their transforms with the bones of the animated armature, and the skinned armatures bones would be posed to match the positions of the empties for every frame of animation, but this seems very tedious and I can't think of anything else.

Thanks to whoever in advance.

Comment: You can try changing the rest pose of the target armature. this can help you https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49768/can-i-set-my-pose-position-like-the-new-rest-position

Comment: I should've said this in the post: I can't change the T-posed armature, it needs to be in that position for a specific program as well as I am trying to add multiple animations to this armature in the same way as above. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26216/935) has two answers that link to addons that should help. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147739/2684771) has a script that configures bones to follow empties, should be easy to adapt to follow a second rig.