# Bind an armature with animation to another armature

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, bones

I have a model of a character with an armature that's already been weight-painted and functions normally. However, I now want to take a different armature with no model and somehow bind certain bones to the modeled armature to make the modeled armature inherit the blank armature's animation.
I've already tried, with the FBX import tool that I'm using, to just import the animation to the existing model and armature, but it seems to dislike the model's bone names and various other problems, so that won't work.
Here's an example of what I want to do, if it's still unclear:

1. Have unmodeled, animated armature
2. Have modeled, static armature
3. ???
4. Modeled armature now inherits unmodeled armature's animation
5. Profit

Comment: If its just bone names you may be able import the armature into blender as an armature rather than a pose and fix the bone names and re-export. Otherwise it gets a lot trickier.

Comment: It hasn't been updated for 2.80 yet but does the Motion Capture Tools addon that I mention [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26260/935) help?